# React MUI multiple select overflow one line display the ellipsis

Tags: select, material-ui, autocomplete

I developed a multiple select component that have checkbox can select all and search. The component used Autocomplete and TextField.
I hope the select input can display the ellipsis when selected overflow one line. I set styles but it didn't work. It display all selected options in input.
When I click the select input it can't wake up the options drop-down box If I set overflow scroll and maxHeight .result is I need click twice .Probably because of the cursor position.

Comment: can you please add the code or create a codesandbox so we can replicate and probably provide a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I added this to the AutoComplete and it worked for me.

```
sx={{
      "& > .MuiAutocomplete-root .MuiFormControl-root .MuiInputBase-root": {flexWrap: "nowrap"}
 }}

renderTags={ 
  (list) => {
    let displayList = list.map((item) => item.label).join(' • ');
    // Render <Typography> elements instead of <Chip> components. Residence 1, Version 1 • Residence 1, Version 5...
      return <Typography
        noWrap={true}
        sx={{ pl: 1 }}
        color="textPrimary"
         >
            {displayList}
        </Typography>;
      },
 }
```